# Populating a table view form JSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have a NSString as result of a URLRequest.

```
  NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   if(responseString && responseString.length) {
                                     //  NSLog(@"DATOS RECIBIDOS EN HISTORIAL=%@", responseString);
                                       NSError *jsonError;
                                       NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                              error:&jsonError];
                                       NSArray *messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];

                                       // Parse and loop through the JSON
                                       for (json in messageArray) {
                                           NSString * code = [json objectForKey:@"code"];

                                           NSDictionary *level2Dict = [json objectForKey:@"client"];
                                           NSString *email =  [level2Dict objectForKey:@"email"];

                                           //NSString * nombre = someObject;
                                           NSLog(@"CODIGO DE CLIENTE=%@",code);
                                           NSLog(@"EMAIL DEL CLIENTE=%@",email);

                                       }
```

Then I convert the string to a NSData that I deserialise into a json string.
Later I am able to iterate the array of dictionaries to get the value from some of the json objects.

But for hours I am trying to pass all this information to a table view, but I am not able. From the above code what should I do to get the needed information to be shown on a table view?

Thank you.

EDITED QUESTION:

```
@interface HistorialReservasViewController () {
       NSArray *messageArray;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(home:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=newBackButton;
    self.title = @"Corona";



    //REQUEST DEL HISTORIAL
    messageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // just so array is not nil


    //1. client , lo tomamos de la variable del sistema
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];//se crea una instancia de la variable del sistema

    //LOS PARAMETROS NECESARIOS SON client y date


    //buscamos client
    NSString *idcliente = [defaults objectForKey:@"idUsuario"];
    NSLog(@"ID CLIENTE=&%@",idcliente);
    NSString *cliente = idcliente;



    NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    NSString        *dateString;

    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"FECHA=%@", dateString);

    NSString *fecha = dateString;

    NSLog(@"CLIENTE=%@",cliente);
    NSLog(@"FECHA=%@",fecha);


    //request


    NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hidden here/?client=%@&date=%@", cliente,fecha]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:apiURL]; // this is using GET, for POST examples see the other answers here on this page
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if(data.length) {
                                   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   if(responseString && responseString.length) {
                                     //  NSLog(@"DATOS RECIBIDOS EN HISTORIAL=%@", responseString);
                                       NSError *jsonError;
                                       NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                              error:&jsonError];
                                          messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];

                                       // Parse and loop through the JSON
                                       for (json in messageArray) {
                                           NSString * code = [json objectForKey:@"code"];

                                           NSDictionary *level2Dict = [json objectForKey:@"client"];
                                           NSString *email =  [level2Dict objectForKey:@"email"];
                                       //   id someObject = [level2Dict objectForKey:@"name"];
                                         //  NSLog(@"NOMBRE===%@",someObject);
                                           //NSString * nombre = someObject;
                                           NSLog(@"CODIGO DE CLIENTE=%@",code);
                                           NSLog(@"EMAIL DEL CLIENTE=%@",email);

                                       }



                                   }
                               }
                           }];

    NSLog(@"NUMERO ED ITEMS=%lu", (unsigned long)messageArray.count);



}




//METODOS PARA LA CONEXION



-(void)home:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapa_segue" sender:self];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [messageArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"code"];
    return cell;
}



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return NO;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Comment: How is your tableview created? Did you set delegate and datasource and implemented needed functions? Provide code for those too please.

Comment: @IxPaka, thank you, what you see above is inside the viewDidLoad method, all other table view related methods are there also. Table is shown , but obviusly empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your data to your tableview at all. You need to create global array and initializes this array in viewDidLoad, populate it like you do and use it in your tableview functions.

```
NSArray *messageArray;
```

in view did load change this line

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    messageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // just so array is not nil
    messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];
}
```

And use this array to populate your tableview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [messageArray count]; //this will ensure you will have as many cells in your table view as there are values in your array
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //here you use your array and fill cell with your data
    // you need to have a UILabel in cell which is called "codeLabel" but feel free to name it whatever you want
    cell.codeLabel.text = [[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"code"]; //to fill your codelabel with code value from array
    cell.otherLabel.text = [[messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"other"]; //just another value

    return cell;
}
```

#### EDIT

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if(data.length) {
                               NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                               if(responseString && responseString.length) {
                                 //  NSLog(@"DATOS RECIBIDOS EN HISTORIAL=%@", responseString);
                                   NSError *jsonError;
                                   NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                          error:&jsonError];
                                      messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];
                                      NSLog(@"NUMERO ED ITEMS=%lu", (unsigned long)messageArray.count);
                                     //all UI updates must be called from main thread, thats why reload data must be wrapped in this call for more info google "ios GCD"
                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue){
                                         [tableView reloadData];
                                     }

                                   // Parse and loop through the JSON
                                   for (json in messageArray) {
                                       NSString * code = [json objectForKey:@"code"];

                                       NSDictionary *level2Dict = [json objectForKey:@"client"];
                                       NSString *email =  [level2Dict objectForKey:@"email"];
                                   //   id someObject = [level2Dict objectForKey:@"name"];
                                     //  NSLog(@"NOMBRE===%@",someObject);
                                       //NSString * nombre = someObject;
                                       NSLog(@"CODIGO DE CLIENTE=%@",code);
                                       NSLog(@"EMAIL DEL CLIENTE=%@",email);

                                   }



                               }
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented your code, but messageArray.count = 0.

Comment: @user4619034 oh I forgot, you need to reload your tableview when you populate your array, add `[yourTableView reloadData];` at the end of your `viewDidLoad function`

Comment: You are right, but messageArray.count is 0 in any case.

Comment: @user4619034 try to populate it like this `messageArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"objects"]];`

Comment: The same result, messageArray.count = 0

Comment: But don't worry, I will try it using another procedure.

Comment: @user4619034 you need to put print value and reload command after data have been downloaded, you are doing it wrong right now, i'll update my answer for you

Comment: @user4619034 there you go, I updated it, try it now, what you were doing before, you werent waiting for data to download, thats what asynchronous means, it runs on another thread, so you started downloading data, printed value and after that you finished downloading.